# In Spring Boot with Postgres, how do I get the currently logged in user in my audit history table, which is using Postgres trigger functions?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security, triggers

I am trying to implement audit history in my application which is using Spring Boot with Postgres as the database. If I use the usual "boilerplate" columns, shown below, with every table in my database, it's easy to find the user who did the last modification to a row.

```
@Data
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<T> {

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(updatable = false)
    protected T createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    protected Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    protected T lastModifiedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    protected Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

However, I now want to check every edit done to a row by any user. I'm trying to implement this by using Postgres Trigger Functions as shown below. The problem I'm facing is how to get the "**current_user**", who called the save/update query on that particular row.

```
-- My Data Table
CREATE TABLE data (
id integer,
value integer
);

-- My Changelog table
CREATE TABLE changelog (
id integer,
changes text,
user text,
changed_on timestamp
);
```

```
-- My Trigger Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_history() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    changes text;
BEGIN
    changes := '''';
    IF old.value <> new.value THEN
    changes := CONCAT(changes, old.value, ':', new.value)
    INSERT INTO
            changelog(changes, user, changed_on)
            VALUES(changes, current_user, NOW());
    END IF
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

-- My Trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON data FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE data_history();
```

I can get the username of the current logged-in user via the below code in my Spring Boot App:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

But how do I pass it to the trigger function?

Comment: The current uses from the PLSQL pov, is the one that made the database connection, not the user that has been logged in to your application. Those are different things. So unless you set that in some custom session variable (a sql connection session with `SET <varname> = <value>` upon the retrieval of the connection (and reset it afterwards) this is simply not possible).

Comment: @M.Deinum, Cool. Thanks. Will try to find some workaround. Maybe I'll keep the lastModifiedBy boilerplate column in the tables and use that instead in the trigger.